# How to use delta time in a Java game?

Tags: java, timedelta

I am trying to animate a simple Java game, which includes the movement of a ball. My current calculation for the ball is: current X position + X direction * ball speed, and the same for Y. I want to incorporate delta time in order to ensure the ball is always moving at the same speed. Currently I have:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then in the game loop I have

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
int changeInTime = int(time-currentTime);
time = currentTime;
```

I would like to use delta time to ensure the ball has moved 1 pixel in the X,Y directions every 30 milliseconds. Calculating changeInTime/40 moves the ball faster than I could see it, and then it gets stuck in a corner. Any ideas?

Comment: There's an entire Game Development StackExchange site. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13008/how-to-get-and-use-delta-time

Comment: isn't your `changeInTime` negative? Shouldn't it be `int changeInTime = (int) (currentTime-time)`, also use `System.nanoTime()`, or you will have funny glitches when OS clock changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make a game , It could be a good idea to use a thread in order to animate the ball , if you do this, you can delay the ball with ´sleep()´ method.

Comment: And how did you come to the conclusion that there is no rendering thread, and that it doesn't sleep after the frame is drawn? The fact that thread sleeps doesn't deny the necessity to compute the amount of time elapsed.

Comment: I did use a thread to animate the ball, but the issue I am having without delta time is that the ball seems to suddenly slow down and then speed up.